# Need Details Information about SIP Transaction

Tags: transactions, udp, request, response, sip

Could you please anybody help me about SIP transaction? I need details information about transaction like rfc document, only for sip transaction. Moreover, need to handle 407 and 401 case handle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to know, when we will call that SIP transaction is completed or not. Moreover, for 407 and 401 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIP transactions are described in detail in chapter 17 of RFC 3261. Section [17.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.1.1) deals specifically with the INVITE client transaction. There is also a correction defined in RFC 6026.

From a transaction perspective, there is nothing special with 401 or 407 responses: client sends ACK and transitions to the completed state where it eventually will terminate (depending on transport type).

Comment: Thanks. For 401 and 407 response, when client get these response from server side, can I say this is a complete transaction? or for complete the transaction ACK will include too.

Comment: Yes, sending an ACK is part of the transaction.